# Best way to convert list of dicts to space separated strings in python

Tags: python-3.x

Given a list of dicts, how can I extract the values from it to get the desired output below. I am trying to see if I can use list comprehension or a lambda expression.

input:

```
"command": [
  {
    "arg1": "--abc",
    "value": "cde"
  },
  {
    "arg2": "--efg",
    "value": 2
  }
]
```

output:
`--abc=cde --efg=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a short code something like this:

```py
commands = [
  {
    "arg1": "--abc",
    "value": "cde"
  },
  {
    "arg2": "--efg",
    "value": 2
  }
]


print(" ".join("=".join(map(str, dictionary.values())) for dictionary in commands))
```

Which gives you the result `--abc=cde --efg=2`, Hope it helps :D